# How to show answer respective to its ID from database once the ID is clicked?

Tags: php, database

This is a FAQ page. I am currently having problem to show the answer with its respective question. The page is able to show all the questions in the database as I have already placed them in the loop. However ,when I clicked on any questions to view the answer. It will only collapse the first question and the show answer that appears first in my database. I want it to collapse and show the answer with respective to its question when I clicked on the different questions. How should I go about doing it?

Below is my code:

```
<h1>FAQ</h1>    <?php

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq where status='Enabled' ORDER BY id ASC;");
     if($result >= 1 ){             
        echo '<hr class="colorgraph">';   
        $i=1;



  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))

        {  $id = $row["id"];  

?>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"> //this is dropdown box.
         <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                <?= $row['question'] ?></h4>
        </a></div> // the user has to click this to dropdown to see the information below

       <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">

      <div class="panel-body"><?= $row['answer'] ?></div> // this is the information that will be shown once it dropped down

         </div>
        </div>
```

```
     <?php

      $i++;  }

    }else{
        echo "No Questions Found<br></table>";
    }

                              ?>
```

Comment: Add the question ID to the where clause for getting answers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977000/php-javascript-report-to-show-line-details-and-summary

Answer (score 1):

MOdify your Query and pass and id either from the URL using GET or using jQuery via POST and filter the results for that ID only.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM faq where status='Enabled' AND id = {My ID here} ORDER BY id ASC;");
```